# How can provide your own keys in firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have such a structure in firebase.

[image]

And such a method in Angular:

```
addUserToBase(
  email: string,
  name: string,
  surname: string,
  position: string,
  userId: string
) {
  return this.http.post<User> (
    url: `https://[API_KEY].firebasedatabase.app/users.json`,
    body: {
      userId: userId,
      email: email,
      name: name,
      surname: surname,
      position: position;
    }
  );
}
```

And here's a question for you, how to send your own in this method instead of a random key in firebase? I will add that I do not want to use the built-in firebase functions.

Comment: (not the downvoter) Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the REST API, you can use the `PUT` verb instead of the `POST` verb to specify the entire path.

Using `POST` means that Firebase will create a child under the location where call it, and write the data you specify there.

Using `PUT` means that Firebase will write the data exactly that the location that you specified.

So if you put data to `https://yourdb.firebasedatabase.app/users/yourid.json`, it will write in that precise location without creating a new child.